# Parallel Library: does a delay on one degree of parallelism delay all of them?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have a ConcurrentBag `urls` whose items are being processed in parallel (nothing is being written back to the collection):

```
         urls.AsParallel<UrlInfo>().WithDegreeOfParallelism(17).ForAll( item =>
              UrlInfo info = MakeSynchronousWebRequest(item);
             (myProgress as IProgress<UrlInfo>).Report(info);
         });
```

I have the timeout set to 30 seconds in the web request.  When a url that is very slow to respond is encountered, all of the parallel processing grinds to a halt.  Is this expected behavior, or should I be searching out some problem in my code?

Here's the progress :

```
        myProgress = new Progress<UrlInfo>( info =>
        {

            Action action = () =>
            {

                Interlocked.Increment(ref itested);
                if (info.status == UrlInfo.UrlStatusCode.dead)
                {
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref idead);
                    this.BadUrls.Add(info);
                }

                dead.Content = idead.ToString();
                tested.Content = itested.ToString();                    
            };
            try
            {
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action);
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

        });
```

Comment: That ought to be async

Comment: I haven't been able to get the AsParallel to work with async web requests and Progress reporting back to the UI.  Are you saying that the behavior I'm seeing is expected?

Comment: Use `await Task.WhenAll(urls.AsParallel().Select(async item => { await ... }))`

Comment: If you only have a single async operation, you can return its `Task` directly instead of making the lambda async.

Comment: Note that you should only call `AsParallel()` if there is a significant **synchronous** step that you want to parallelize.  If all of the work is async, you don't need threading.

Comment: I am trying to spawn as many web requests simultaneously as our bandwidth and my PC will allow.  And now I'm confused (my ignorance to blame) when you say this: `only call AsParallel() if there is a significant synchronous step that you want to parallelize` when before you had said the request should be async.  I'm trying to parallelize synchronous web requests that wait for a timeout.

Comment: I will try the await Task.WhenAll... and see what happens. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3):

It's the expected behavior.  `AsParallel` doesn't return until all the operations are finished.  Since you're making synchronous requests, you've got to wait until your slowest one is finished.  However note that even if you've got one really slow task hogging up a thread, the scheduler continues to schedule new tasks as old ones finish on the remaining threads.

Here's a rather instructive example.  It creates 101 tasks.  The first task hogs one thread for 5000 ms, the 100 others churn on the remaining 20 threads for 1000 ms each.  So it schedules 20 of those tasks and they run for one second each, going through that cycle 5 times to get through all 100 tasks, for a total of 5000 ms.  However if you change the 101 to 102, that means you've got 101 tasks churning on the 20 threads, which will end up taking 6000 ms; that 101th task just didn't have a thread to churn on until the 5 sec mark.  If you change the 101 to, say, 2, you note it still takes 5000 ms because you have to wait for the slow task to complete.

```
static void Main()
{
    ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(21, 21);
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    Enumerable.Range(0, 101).AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(21).ForAll(i => Thread.Sleep(i==0?5000:1000));
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

Comment: Instructive, thanks. But I am still not perfectly clear what conditions cause the Progress to be posted, since I'm not clear on what an "operation" is exactly. A single task running to completion on a single thread?  A single task running to completion on all threads that have been allocated for the parallelization? My UI is being updated by the Progress, but the progress updates stall, and then recommence. It is not as though every item in the enumerable has to have been processed before a Progress update occurs.

Comment: @Tim What does your progress code look like?  There are several ways to do it.

Comment: @Tim Are you launching your `urls.AsParallel()...` block from the UI thread?  If so then the UI thread will also be used for some of the parallel blocks, obviously slowing down responsiveness.  Try launching it from a new thread and all blocks will run on the thread pool, leaving your UI thread free to do updates.

Comment: @Tim see the last section here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997392.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link. But it's not as simple as the link suggests. When I wrap the parallel task in a new task using Task.Factory.StartNew(), I get an InvalidOperationException in mscorlib.dll which isn't being trapped by my `catch(AggregateException aex)` block within the parallel loop, so I'm not even sure where the problem is happening.

Comment: Try using ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem or new Thread.Start instead. Works for me.